# How to filter a dataframe already containing NaN based on entry conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I am starting with one dataframe and I would like to split it into three dataframes depending conditions placed on entry values. For, df1 I would like to only have Person_X values <0.33. For df2, I would like to only have 0.34<Person_X values<0.65. For df3, I would like to only have Person_X values >0.66. I would like NaN to replace integer values that don't fit the requirements.

So, starting with df:

```
In [1]: df=pd.DataFrame({'location':[4991, 8870, 2703, 9674], 
   ...:                  'Person_1': ['NaN', 0.2,0.5,0.7], 
   ...:                  'Person_2':[0.8, 0.45, 'NaN', 0.1]}) 
   ...: df                                                                      
Out[1]: 
   location Person_1 Person_2
0      4991      NaN      0.8
1      8870      0.2     0.45
2      2703      0.5      NaN
3      9674      0.7      0.1
```

I would like to have three dataframes that look like:

```
 df1
   location Person_1 Person_2
0      4991      NaN      NaN
1      8870      0.2     NaN
2      2703      NaN     NaN
3      9674      NaN      0.1

df2
 Out[4]: 
   location Person_1 Person_2
0      4991      NaN      NaN
1      8870      NaN     0.45
2      2703      0.5      NaN
3      9674      NaN      NaN

df3
 Out[4]: 
   location Person_1 Person_2
0      4991      NaN      0.8
1      8870      NaN      NaN
2      2703      NaN      NaN
3      9674      0.7      NaN
```

I have tried something like this for each of the requirements, but since df contains NaN already, I am running into issues.

```
patient_cols=[col for col in df if col.startswith('Person')]
df[patient_cols]=df[patient_cols].applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x>0.33 else x)
df[patient_cols]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use [`pd.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas-dataframe-where):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'location':[4991, 8870, 2703, 9674], 
   'Person_1': [np.nan, 0.2,0.5,0.7], 
                     'Person_2':[0.8, 0.45, np.nan, 0.1]})  

#Just incase your NaN are strings as indicated by your original posts.
df=df.replace('NaN', np.nan) 

df= df.set_index('location')

df1 = df.where(df<.33).reset_index()
df2 = df.where((df>.34) & (df<.65)).reset_index()
df3 = df.where(df>.66).reset_index()

print(df1)
print('\n')
print(df2)
print('\n')
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
   location  Person_1  Person_2
0      4991       NaN       NaN
1      8870       0.2       NaN
2      2703       NaN       NaN
3      9674       NaN       0.1

   location  Person_1  Person_2
0      4991       NaN       NaN
1      8870       NaN      0.45
2      2703       0.5       NaN
3      9674       NaN       NaN

   location  Person_1  Person_2
0      4991       NaN       0.8
1      8870       NaN       NaN
2      2703       NaN       NaN
3      9674       0.7       NaN
```

Comment: I would add `df=df.replace('NaN', np.nan)` to the beginning, since the OP's initial dataframe doesn't have np.nan values.

Comment: @MrNobody33 That seems wise.